# KivyMD not able to change the size of MDBottomNavigation

Tags: kivy, kivymd

Im Not able to change the size/height of my MDBottomNavigaton, can anyone help out, please?
'height: any_number' isn't working

MDBottomNavigation:

```
            panel_color: 0,0,0,1
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: "gambling_nav"
                icon: 'gift'
                text_color_normal: 1, 1, 1, 1
                GamblingScreen:

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: "memestonks_nav"
                icon: 'rocket'
                text_color_normal: 1, 1, 1, 1
                MemestocksScreen:

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'watchlist_nav'
                icon: 'eye'
                text_color_normal: 1, 0, 1, 1
                WatchlistScreen:

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'news_nav'
                icon: 'newspaper'
                text_color_normal: 1, 1, 1, 1
                NewsScreen:

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'discuss_nav'
                icon: 'chat'
                text_color_normal: 1, 0, 1, 1
                DiscussScreen:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MDBottomNavigation height is set to 56dp by default, which is done to incorporate the
Material-Design [specifications](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#specs) for BottomNavigation.

The only way to change this, is to edit line 224 in the [bottomnavigation.py](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/uix/bottomnavigation.py) file.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!